# Including my own scripts in the admin-repo with gitolite

Tags: gitolite

I have some scripts that I call from a common hook of gitolite, I want to manage them from the configuration directories of the admin-repo repository so I can modify them more easily and they will be versioned also.

I have tried by adding a new directory and by tracking it with `git add`, but it does not work as expected. Maybe gitolite has some way to do this but I have not found any information on how to do such a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: the following is for [Gitolite V3 or g3](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g3why.html) only.

You can add/manage them in their own directories, namely the ["`hooks/common`"](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/cust.html#hooks) sub-directory if the gitolite-admin (create it if it doesn't exists).

That directory will appear in your Gitolite server in ~/.gitolite/hooks/common, and if you define a [`LOCAL_CODE` rc variable](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/cust.html#localcode)) pointing to it, it will be taken into account.
You might need to follow the push of the `gitolite-admin` repo by a **`gitolite setup --hooks-only`** on the server though.

Comment: I was using an old version of gitolite, major version: 2. I updated and tried your suggestion, it works perfectly. Thanks.